# how to compare Optional<Long> with Long

Tags: java, option-type

I need to compare two cities ids.
The first one is Optional < Long>, the second one is Long.

```
  public boolean isEqual(Comment comment) {
    return userService.findById(comment.getUser().getId())
        .map(user -> user.getCity().getId()) // Optional <Long>
        .filter(user -> user
            .equals(postService.findById(comment.getPost().getId())
                .map(p -> p.getUser().getCity().getId())))  // Long
        .isPresent();
  }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead of `map`. Right now you seem to have an `Optional<Optional<Long>>` and hence its cumbersome to work with.

Comment: What does it mean to compare a Long with `Optional.empty()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compare optionals directly:

```
public boolean isEqual(Comment comment) {
  Optional<Long> userCityFromComment = userService
    .findById(comment.getUser().getId())
    .map(user -> user.getCity().getId());
  Optional<Long> userCityFromPost = postService
    .findById(comment.getPost().getId())
    .map(p -> p.getUser().getCity().getId());
  return userCityFromComment.equals(userCityFromPost);
}
```

Note that `Optional.empty().equals(Optional.empty())` is `true`.